# DatePicker does not allow to choose October dates

Tags: jquery

Problem is really weird. 
On click of textbox, calender appears. If i choose sep/nov date any month except October, works fine with validation.
But if I select 1-10 to 31-10 then error appears, Please enter valid date.
I am not typing myself or setting anything.

Bellow my html code.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">Select date (optional):<br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="istartDate" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start date">
      <span class="input-group-addon input-help">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar txt-color-sysmechBlue"></i>
      </span>
     </div>
     <span class="help-block"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Find below jquery code.

```
$('#istartDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    prevText: '<i class="left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="right"></i>'
});
```

Comment: create a working fiddle for this

Comment: Can you create jsfiidle demo for it?